# Vb.net: object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Exception:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Code:

```
    For Each p As Panel In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Panel)()
        arr.Add(p.BackColor.ToString())
        Me.Controls.Remove(p)
    Next
```

The line:

```
arr.Add(p.BackColor.ToString())
```

How can I fix this thing?

Comment: It's not a part of your question, but be careful with that `Me.Controls.Remove(p)` line.  It won't clear out all of the panels since you are changing the collection as you iterate through them.  Also, it won't get rid of the panels from memory.  For that, you need to call `Dispose()` on them.

Comment: To fix the possible `Remove` problem, just change `.OfType(Of Panel)()` to `.OfType(Of Panel)().ToArray()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably declared `arr` something like this:

```
Dim arr As List(Of String)
```

You need to initialize the variable to an instance of `List(Of String)` before you can use it. Change it to:

```
Dim arr As New List(Of String)
```